# Make Eclipse reference maven projects and not jars

Tags: eclipse, maven

I'm trying to have the projects within my workspace to reference each other directly, instead of the jar files from the maven repo. That used to work perfectly fine when having all the projects in the same folder (eclipse workspace) and using `mvn install` and `mvn eclipse:eclipse`. However, now it's not working and I believe it's due to the fact that the projects are not located in the workspace folder, but in my local GIT repo, from where I import them into Eclipse. I assume that I need to set some variable somewhere, but couldn't find anything on this on the interwebs. I've also tried using the eclipse maven plugin, but I got into other problems that completely broke my setup. Using `-Declipse.useProjectReferences=true` doesn't help either. I'm grateful for any hint!

Answer (score 2):

I suddenly began having this problem after a reboot (??).

What worked for me was:

- on my project's context menu, open "Properties"
- Java Build Path tab: add the projects which need to be referenced
- Order and Export tab: move these projects to the top of the list

Answer (score 1):

There's a setting on each Project to control this behavior. Right-click to open the project Properties, then select the **Maven** section; there you'll find the option *Resolve dependencies from Workspace projects*.

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have a Maven section in the project properties.

Comment: That means either you don't have m2e installed, or the project is not configured as a Maven project. If you want to use local resolution instead of repo resolution in Eclipse, you'll need both of those things to be true.

Comment: OK, installed m2e, upgraded my projects to Maven projects, I have enabled dependency resolving from workspace projects, still no success...

Comment: It's not clear what you're observing and how it differs from what you expect.